Using d2lang and the sql_table shape, can I add comments to column descriptions?
As title states, it would be nice to add comments in ER tables. Something like:
car: {
  shape: sql_table
  id: int {constraint: primary_key}
  make: string "This is a comment describing the column"
}

or maybe
car: {
  shape: sql_table
  id: int {constraint: primary_key}
  make: string {comment: "This is a comment describing the column"}
}

Compare with Mermaid comments in ER: https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/entityRelationshipDiagram.html
PERSON {
    string driversLicense PK "The license #"
    string(99) firstName "Only 99 characters are allowed"
}


I don't see an official way to do this in the docs, but you could use the constraint field to store anything else along with other constraints:
car: {
  shape: sql_table
  id: int {constraint: primary_key}
  make: string {constraint: ["This is a comment describing the column"; foreign_key]}
}


